# Java input parsing with delimiter | (pipe)

Tags: java, parsing

I know pipe is a special character and I need to use:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = input.next();

        String[] columns = line.split("\\|");
```

to use the pipe as a delimiter. But it doesn't work as desired when I parse from the command line.

e.g.

When I parse from a file, this just works. However, when the input has a white space, whenever I parse the input from command line, it gives me out of bounds error, because it splits the word into two array element.

input

`a|5|Hello|3`

output:

```
columns[0] = "a";
columns[1] = "5";
columns[2] = "Hello";
columns[3] = "3";
```

bug:

input:

a|5|Hello World|3;

output:

```
columns[0] = "a";
columns[1] = "5";
columns[2] = "Hello";
columns[3] = "World";
columns[4] = "3";
```

I want columns[3] as "Hello World". How can I fix this?

Comment: You might've wanted to start off with `System.out.println(line);`, which will tell you the problem is with `next`, not `split` (use `nextLine`).

Comment: What does the javadoc of Scanner say about what a "token" is? What does the javadoc of Scanner.next() say?

Comment: @Dukeling, thank you. using {input.nextLine()} instead of {input.next()} fixed the issue.

Comment: Traditionally command line arguments with spaces or other special characters need to have them either escaped or quoted when the command is given.  If you have a good enough reason to use pipe as your delimiter, you'll need to assume that your users know how to properly do the escapes when calling it. Personally I'd pick a different character that won't be parsed by the shell interpreter in use, then read entire line, parse, validate, and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the data from user by using nextLine() instead of only next().

In my case its working fine [just click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umb53.png)  and check the source code ..

Answer (score 0):

**next()** can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by space. Also, **next()** places the cursor in the same line after reading the input. **nextLine()** reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line n).

Answer (score 0):

> A *Scanner* breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

To overcome, you should use `nextline()` method instead.

```
String line = input.nextline();
```